# can I use haar cascade to detect something other than faces?

Tags: opencv

I'm new to facial recognition. And I just read the paper written by Viola & Jones.
Just curious, If one can track down some thing other than faces using haar cascade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, haar cascade can be trained in openCV. Take a look at these two links for a hint:

http://opencvuser.blogspot.in/2011/08/creating-haar-cascade-classifier-aka.html
http://note.sonots.com/SciSoftware/haartraining.html

Just a small tip: it takes considerable time and you must start with a whole lot of training data if you want a dependable result.

Comment: hello sir your photo remove library use but wait for some time then result find out so please how to reduce time waiting photo object remove let me know how to my question solve out ....

Comment: @RamaniHitesh are you asking an unrelated question? Please clarify, I'm not sure what you are talking about.

Comment: your library much more time so how to reduce  this one ?

Comment: @RamaniHitesh which library? Can you please provide link? Or maybe ask a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

"Just curious, If one can track down some thing other than faces using haar cascade."

yes, ofc. you can.

there are a lot of other cascade files in the data folder, and tools like train_cascade to train your own in the opencv set for that (it just takes a lot of images and time to do).

also, besides haar cascades, there are lbp, hog and softcascades

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Version 2.4.6 includes:

> Directory of \OpenCV246\opencv\data\haarcascades
>
> haarcascade_eye.xml haarcascade_eye_tree_eyeglasses.xml
>   haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml
>   haarcascade_frontalface_alt_tree.xml
>   haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml haarcascade_fullbody.xml
>   haarcascade_lefteye_2splits.xml haarcascade_lowerbody.xml
>   haarcascade_mcs_eyepair_big.xml haarcascade_mcs_eyepair_small.xml
>   haarcascade_mcs_leftear.xml haarcascade_mcs_lefteye.xml
>   haarcascade_mcs_mouth.xml haarcascade_mcs_nose.xml
>   haarcascade_mcs_rightear.xml haarcascade_mcs_righteye.xml
>   haarcascade_mcs_upperbody.xml haarcascade_profileface.xml
>   haarcascade_righteye_2splits.xml haarcascade_smile.xml
>   haarcascade_upperbody.xml